# Convert Javascript value into a link?

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

How am I able to convert the user input into a clickable link within the modal? (user entries will be in a URL format e.g. www.bbc.co.uk). The code I have used is purely from w3c schools and am experimenting how modules could be optimized.
I have added the code below.

```html
  <br><b>URL</b> <input type="text" size="40" value="" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" title="Enter the URL of a web page" onchange="displayURL()">

<br><br><br><br><br>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    font-family: foco;
    
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
    
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.3s
    
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #4286f4;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}


}
</style>



<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>DEMO</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Click on the link:</p>
      <p id="skkr"></p>
      <a id="skkr" href="IM LOST"></a>
      <script>
function displayURL() {
    document.getElementById("skkr").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("url").value;
}

</script>

    </div>
   
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very simple, you have to put the data read from the input box into an anchor tag:

```html
  <br><b>URL</b> <input type="text" size="40" value="" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" title="Enter the URL of a web page" onchange="displayURL()">

<br><br><br><br><br>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    font-family: foco;
    
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
    
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.3s
    
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #4286f4;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}


}
</style>



<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>DEMO</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Click on the link:</p>
      <p id="skkr"></p>
      <a id="skkr" href="IM LOST"></a>
      <script>
function displayURL() {
    var readValue=document.getElementById("url").value;
    document.getElementById("skkr").innerHTML = '<a href="'+readValue+'">'+readValue+'</a>';
}

</script>

    </div>
   
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

The important part is:

```
var readValue=document.getElementById("url").value;
document.getElementById("skkr").innerHTML = '<a href="'+readValue+'">'+readValue+'</a>';
```

Comment: So if I add "http://" before first " '+readValue " the user will be actually able follow the link as well? only if the URL does not contain it already

Comment: @TomJacob I am assuming the user should have a restriction to enter http:// or https:// in the textbox.. If you prefer you should not restrict the user then you can check if the url starts with the http:// if not yes you can add http://

Comment: @TomJacob Hope my answer helps you out. If you need further help ping me..

Answer (score 1):

W3 Schools has a nice little demo for just this thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a string as a hyperlink.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
    var result = str.link("https://www.w3schools.com");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp for reference will guide you further.

Hopefully you can figure out how to target your element to update with your user input from the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the id 'skkr'. That's wrong.

Remove the id 'skkr' from this line `<p id="skkr"></p>`

Next, update the function displayURL() like so:

```
var link = document.getElementById("skkr");
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
link.setAttribute("href",url);
link.innerHTML = url;
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing :) have removed the 2nd "skkr" in my actual code

Comment: You mean you removed it from the <p> tag, right? Does it work now?